# Scala function - Type mismatch. Required: Null. Found: String

Tags: scala, function, type-mismatch

I have a problem with type mismatch in Scala Function. Compiler returns an error:

```
  def isLarger(inputNum: Int) = {
      var res = null
      if (inputNum.>(10)) {
          res = "aaa"
        }
      res
      }
```

If inputNum larger than 10, return String "aaa" if not, return null.
But Type match.
Why? Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add type declaration

```
var res: String = null
```

By the way, you don't need a `var`. If-else is an expression

```
def isLarger(inputNum: Int) = {
  val res: String = 
    if (inputNum > 10)
      "aaa"
    else null
  res
}
```

The concept of absent value is better expressed with `Option` rather than `null`

```
def isLarger(inputNum: Int) =
  if (inputNum > 10)
    Some("aaa")
  else None
```

This can be shortened with `Option.when` (courtesy of **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez**)

```
def isLarger(inputNum: Int) = 
  Option.when(inputNum > 10)("aaa")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir~ It's very nice of you ~ : )

Comment: You may also use `Option.when(inputNum > 10)("aaa")`